# Links in footnotes in pdf are broken

Tags: links

The dashed line in the image shows what will be entered into the browser when pressing the link. When TeX splits the link on two lines the html markup seems to only be applied to the top row.

I'm guessing I need to switch package for generating web links. But maybe it is something simpler?

[image]

```
%% LyX 2.3.6.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,australian]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{some section}

text with a footnote\footnote{https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/standard-installer-command-line-options}.


\end{document}
```

Comment: The downvote (not me) probably stems from the fact that you haven't provided an MWE. As such, people are unable (or at least very much more unwilling) to help you. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: I reckon this link is recognized by the PDF viewer (for example Skim on OSX). If you generate a real link with `\url` or `\href`, there should be no issue.

Comment: Thanks @TeddyvanJerry it was exactly like that

Answer (score 2):

As was noted in the comments I was fooled by my pdf-viewer

Note the difference in the below TeX export

```
.....

    \begin{document}
    
    \section{some section}
    
    text with a footnote\footnote{https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/standard-installer-command-line-options}.
    
    text with a footnote and a link that works \footnote{\href{https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/standard-installer-command-line-options}{https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/standard-installer-command-line-options}}.
    \end{document}
```

And in LyX you mark the text and press the link button:

[image]

And then it will look like below when editing:
[image]